# how to integrate twitter with phonegap ios

Tags: javascript, ios, twitter, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using the phonegap 2.9.0 and trying to implement twitter for an app i am building for ios.

i am following this [tut](http://oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Twitter-integration-on-PhoneGap-using-ChildBrowser-and-OAuth-for-iOS-and-Android-Platforms) but havent gotten much luck with it . implemented child browser using [visit](http://oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Implementing-ChildBrowser-plugin-in-PhoneGap-for-Android-and-iOS-platforms) and since its cordovo.plst is deprecated added the following line in config.xml

```
<feature name="ChildBrowserCommand">
    <param name="ios-package" value="ChildBrowserCommand" />
</feature>
```

in my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jsOAuth-1.3.6.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="ChildBrowser.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function onBodyLoad() {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            }

            function onDeviceReady() {
                var root = this;
                cb = window.plugins.childBrowser;
                if (!localStorage.getItem(twitterKey)) {
                    $("#loginBtn").show();
                    $("#logoutBtn").hide();
                }
                else {
                    $("#loginBtn").hide();
                    $("#logoutBtn").show();
                }

                if (cb != null) {
                    cb.onLocationChange = function(loc) {
                        root.locChanged(loc);
                    };
                    cb.onClose = function() {
                        root.onCloseBrowser()
                    };
                    cb.onOpenExternal = function() {
                        root.onOpenExternal();
                    };

                }



            }

            function onCloseBrowser() {
                console.log("onCloseBrowser!");
            }

            function locChanged(loc) {
                console.log("locChanged!");
            }

            function onOpenExternal() {
                console.log("onOpenExternal!");
            }

        </script>
        <!--Below is the code for twitter-->
        <script>
            // GLOBAL VARS
            var oauth; // It Holds the oAuth data request
            var requestParams; // Specific param related to request
            var options = {
                consumerKey: 'CONSUMER KEy', // YOUR Twitter CONSUMER_KEY
                consumerSecret: 'CONSUMER_SECRET', // YOUR Twitter CONSUMER_SECRET
                callbackUrl: "http://www.textalert.com/"}; // YOU have to replace it on one more Place
            var twitterKey = "twtrKey"; // This key is used for storing Information related


            var Twitter = {
                init: function() {
                    // Apps storedAccessData , Apps Data in Raw format
                    var storedAccessData, rawData = localStorage.getItem(twitterKey);
                    // here we are going to check whether the data about user is already with us.
                    if (localStorage.getItem(twitterKey) !== null) {
                        // when App already knows data
                        storedAccessData = JSON.parse(rawData); //JSON parsing
                        //options.accessTokenKey = storedAccessData.accessTokenKey; // data will be saved when user first time signin
                        options.accessTokenSecret = storedAccessData.accessTokenSecret; // data will be saved when user first first signin

                        // javascript OAuth take care of everything for app we need to provide just the options
                        oauth = OAuth(options);
                        oauth.get('https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json?skip_status=true',
                                function(data) {
                                    var entry = JSON.parse(data.text);
                                    console.log("USERNAME: " + entry.screen_name);
                                }
                        );
                    }
                    else {
                        // we have no data for save user
                        oauth = OAuth(options);
                        oauth.get('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
                                function(data) {
                                    requestParams = data.text;
                                    cb.showWebPage('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?' + data.text); // This opens the Twitter authorization / sign in page
                                    cb.onLocationChange = function(loc) {
                                        Twitter.success(loc);
                                    }; // Here will will track the change in URL of ChildBrowser
                                },
                                function(data) {
                                    console.log("ERROR: " + data);
                                }
                        );
                    }
                },
                /*
                 When ChildBrowser's URL changes we will track it here.
                 We will also be acknowledged was the request is a successful or unsuccessful
                 */
                success: function(loc) {

                    // Here the URL of supplied callback will Load

                    /*
                     Here Plugin will check whether the callback Url matches with the given Url
                     */
                    if (loc.indexOf("http://www.textalert.com/?") >= 0) {

                        // Parse the returned URL
                        var index, verifier = '';
                        var params = loc.substr(loc.indexOf('?') + 1);

                        params = params.split('&');
                        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                            var y = params[i].split('=');
                            if (y[0] === 'oauth_verifier') {
                                verifier = y[1];
                            }
                        }

                        // Here we are going to change token for request with token for access

                        /*
                         Once user has authorised us then we have to change the token for request with token of access
                         here we will give data to localStorage.
                         */
                        oauth.get('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token?oauth_verifier=' + verifier + '&' + requestParams,
                                function(data) {
                                    var accessParams = {};
                                    var qvars_tmp = data.text.split('&');
                                    for (var i = 0; i < qvars_tmp.length; i++) {
                                        var y = qvars_tmp[i].split('=');
                                        accessParams[y[0]] = decodeURIComponent(y[1]);
                                    }

                                    $('#oauthStatus').html('<span style="color:green;">Success!</span>');
                                    $('#stage-auth').hide();
                                    $('#stage-data').show();
                                    oauth.setAccessToken([accessParams.oauth_token, accessParams.oauth_token_secret]);

                                    // Saving token of access in Local_Storage
                                    var accessData = {};
                                    accessData.accessTokenKey = accessParams.oauth_token;
                                    accessData.accessTokenSecret = accessParams.oauth_token_secret;

                                    // Configuring Apps LOCAL_STORAGE
                                    console.log("TWITTER: Storing token key/secret in localStorage");
                                    localStorage.setItem(twitterKey, JSON.stringify(accessData));

                                    oauth.get('https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json?skip_status=true',
                                            function(data) {
                                                var entry = JSON.parse(data.text);
                                                console.log("TWITTER USER: " + entry.screen_name);
                                                $("#welcome").show();
                                                document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "welcome " + entry.screen_name;
                                                successfulLogin();
                                                // Just for eg.
                                                app.init();
                                            },
                                            function(data) {
                                                console.log("ERROR: " + data);
                                            }
                                    );

                                    // Now we have to close the child browser because everthing goes on track.

                                    window.plugins.childBrowser.close();
                                },
                                function(data) {
                                    console.log(data);


                                }
                        );
                    }
                    else {
                        // Just Empty
                    }
                },
                tweet: function() {
                    var storedAccessData, rawData = localStorage.getItem(twitterKey);

                    storedAccessData = JSON.parse(rawData); // Paring Json
                    options.accessTokenKey = storedAccessData.accessTokenKey; // it will be saved on first signin
                    options.accessTokenSecret = storedAccessData.accessTokenSecret; // it will be save on first login

                    // javascript OAuth will care of else for app we need to send only the options
                    oauth = OAuth(options);
                    oauth.get('https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json?skip_status=true',
                            function(data) {
                                var entry = JSON.parse(data.text);
                                Twitter.post();
                            }
                    );
                },
                /*
                 We now have the data to tweet
                 */
                post: function() {
                    var theTweet = $("#tweet").val(); // You can change it with what else you likes.

                    oauth.post('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json',
                            {'status': theTweet, // javascript OAuth encodes this
                                'trim_user': 'true'},
                    function(data) {
                        var entry = JSON.parse(data.text);
                        console.log(entry);

                        // just for eg.
                        done();
                    },
                            function(data) {
                                console.log(data);
                            }
                    );
                }

            }

            function done() {
                $("#tweet").val('');
            }


            function successfulLogin() {
                $("#loginBtn").hide();
                $("#logoutBtn,#tweet,#tweeter,#tweetBtn,#tweetText").show();

            }

            function logOut() {
                //localStorage.clear();
                window.localStorage.removeItem(twitterKey);
                document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "Please Login to use this app";
                $("#loginBtn").show();
                $("#logoutBtn,#tweet,#tweeter,#tweetText,#tweetBtn").hide();

            }

        </script>
        <!--Code for Twitter ends here-->
    </head>
    <body onload="onBodyLoad()">





        <h4>Oodles Twitter App</h4>

        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Login using Twitter</th>
                <th>
                    <button id="loginBtn" onclick="Twitter.init()">Login</button>
                    <button id="logoutBtn" onclick="logOut();">Logout</button>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="tweetText" style="display:none;">
                <td colspan="2"><textarea id="tweet" style="display:none;"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="tweetBtn" style="display:none;">
                <td colspan="2" align="right">
                    <button id="tweeter" onclick="Twitter.tweet();" style="display:none">Tweet</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><div id="welcome">Please Login to use this app</div></td></tr>
        </table>


    </body>
</html>
```

On clicking the login button i get  **ERROR: [object Object]** this error any help would be much appreciated thankyou

Answer (score 0):

hi use TWITTER plugin for Phonegap IOS check [Link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/Twitter)